# why there is no a straighfoward "remove" method in javascript array?

Tags: javascript

I'm not very experienced in javascript. I always have a question which is: why javascript array doesn't have a `remove()` method?

Isn't that good to have APIs as:

`remove(index)` : delete an item by its index and return deleted element

`remove(func)`: delete items who match the criteria specified by the func and return a array of deleted items, for example:

```
let deleteStudents = studentArray.remove(s => s.age < 18);
```

so why there are no such useful methods in javascript and we have to use non-intuitive  `splice` method?

Comment: Sure there is - with `.filter`. (It doesn't mutate the existing array, but that's a good thing in most cases - keeping things immutable makes code easier to reason about), If you want to remove a single index with `splice`, that's quite easy, you just have to pass one more argument to it, a `1`.

Comment: There are Array methods to accomplish both removing by index and by condition. You'll want to use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) for index-based removal and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for removing by condition

Comment: if you are using a pattern of code a lot (removing items based on a result of a function, for example) just create your own function

Comment: @JonWarren - splice mutates the array, filter does not, so `filter` is not exactly the equivalent to "splice by condition"

Answer (score 2):

There is. But the function is called `splice`.

To remove item at index `n`:

```
myArray.splice( n, 1 );
```

Comment: but it cannot takes a func

Comment: @secondimage Expecting a function to do multiple things depending on the parameters seems like a "separation of concerns" issue. You should use a different function depending on how you want to handle the removal. `filter` removes based on a predicate, while `splice` is based on position. You shouldn't have one function taking multiple parameters types dispatching on its type.

Comment: `You shouldn't have one function taking multiple parameters types dispatching on its type` - why not? plenty of standard javascript does

Comment: @Bravo I don't think something is necessarily best practice though just because the language has used it previously. Java, Python, and I'm sure others have violated their own style recommendations within their own code. If a function has a fundamentally different behavior, it should be a separate function.

Answer (score 0):

For removing by index, use   `Array.splice(index, remove_count)` method. Example

```
var words = [‘spray’, ‘limit’, ‘elite’, ‘exuberant’, ‘destruction’, ‘present’];

// We will remove the item in index 1. (limit)
words.splice(1, 1);

console.log(words);
// prints [ 'spray', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present' ]
```

For removing by a function, use `filter` method:
It creates a new array based on the function. Example:

```
var words = [‘spray’, ‘limit’, ‘elite’, ‘exuberant’, ‘destruction’, ‘present’];

// Removes words having length less than 6
const result = words.filter(word => word.length < 6); 

console.log(result); // prints [ 'spray', 'limit', 'elite' ]
```